# Laravel session data is gone

Tags: php, laravel

Recently I noticed that laravel session data doesn't work. I mean I can login and etc, but all methods with

```
return back()->withInput()->with('success', 'sucess msg');
```

doesn't work anymore. Nor input neither success message is sent.

For example: I have these routes:

```
Route::get('/profile/{id}', 'Frontend\UserController@profile');
Route::post('/profile', 'Frontend\UserController@update');
```

First route opens a user profile page where he can edit his profile and submit form, then update method is called which is :

```
public function update(Request $request) {

    if($this->userService->validate($request)) {

        if($this->userService->update()) {
            return redirect('/profile/' . $request->id)->with('success', 'Profile updated!');
        }

    }

    return back()->withInput()->with('profile_errors', $this->userService->errors());           

}
```

If user is successfully updated I show him a success message which is accessed in a view like this:

```
        @if(session('success')) 
            <div class="alert alert-success">
              <strong>Success!</strong> {{ session('success')  }}
            </div>              
        @endif
```

I know that this code used to work well. But recently I noticed that it doesn't, and anywhere on the web all success, validation errors and all input data is gone after return redirect or return back() methods. Im quite new in laravel, what should I look for to fix this?

Edit for comment: Here is content of .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: When this happened to me at some point it was because I had an intermediate redirect happening with an `.htaccess` rule before the final redirect. This was causing the flashdata to be lost . Make sure you're not having any extra redirects happening between the `back()..` and when you actually get back.

Comment: I checked .htaccess file, tried to remove some rules but it didn't effect the result. Session data isn't working.

Comment: I noticed that if I comment out \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
inside 'web' middleware group everything works fine. What I want to ask is if it is safe and OK to leave this commented out?

Comment: have you checked middleware kernel `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` commented or not

Comment: @cinik11 any chance you start the session twice?

Comment: What version of laravel and have you updated recently?